# CSS selector for first heading of a div

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="content">
    <img src="#">
    <!-- Text content here -->
</div>
```

This forms the basis for a content page of a website I've made which uses a CMS to manage the content, with the ability to select an image and then a WYSIWYG editor for the text content. An example of the page's HTML that would be output by the CMS is:

```
<div class="content">
    <img src="#">
    <h1>Lorem</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</div>
```

Is there a CSS selector that will select the h1 in the example HTML above? I want to be able to remove the top margin of the heading if the text content section begins with a heading, but I can't do this with a class (since the text content is output by the CMS through a WYSIWYG editor).

Comment: by which property do you want to select h1

Comment: The title does not match the text of the question, which is somewhat vague. Does the `div` content always start with an `img`? What does “text content section begins with a heading” really mean? For example, what if there is text content (no tags) between the `img` and a heading?

Comment: Apologies for not making the question as clear as it should have been, you're right that it was somewhat vague. Fortunately Rohit provided the selector I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this

```
.content > img + h1{
 // css style
}
```

**2nd option**

```
.content > h1:first-child{
// here css
}
```

**3rd**

```
.content h1:first-child{
// here style
}
```

Comment: The options are answers to different questions. The first one answers the question “How can I write a selector that matches any `h1` element that immediately follows an `img` element that is a child of an element in class `content`?” So it could match several `h1` elements (and would never match an `h2` element).

Answer (score 2):

```
.content > h1:first-of-type {margin-top:0;}
```

**that should do the trick**

Comment: I had thought about doing this, but the problem is the page might not always start with a h1 (the user can put anything they want in the WYSIWYG editor), it might start with a h2 or h3 or whatever. If I do what you suggested for h1 through to h6 to remedy this, it will affect more than just a heading that is at the beginning of the text content section (which is the only thing I want to affect).

Comment: h1:first-of-type just means first occurrence of tag. Your markup may have other things before.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, You would just use `h1`.

example

```
h1 {
    margin:0;
}
```

if you want the very first `h1`, you can use `:first-child`

What I normally do when I start coding is that I clean up the browser-made margins and padding.

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

CSS Selectors:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately this doesn't work, because the h1 is not the first child of the .content div, the image is.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.content h1:first-child {
    /* CSS */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately this doesn't work, because the h1 is not the first child of the .content div, the image is.

Answer (score 0):

or you can also use

```
.content h1:first-of-type{
// here style
}
```

Comment: I had thought about doing this, but the problem is the page might not always start with a h1 (the user can put anything they want in the WYSIWYG editor), it might start with a h2 or h3 or whatever. If I do what you suggested for h1 through to h6 to remedy this, it will affect more than just a heading that is at the beginning of the text content section (which is the only thing I want to affect).

Comment: than try all the heading they are only six